# Hyperledger fabric node sdk register user give me [Error: unable to verify the first certificate]

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric-ca

I am using below code for register the user, using the farbic node sdk. I am getting the error. I have passed the all the certificate in connection json. still i am facing this error. Please any one can suggest me. How to use the tls using fabric-node-sdk

> [Error: unable to verify the first certificate]

connection.json

```
{
"name": "org-example",
"version": "1.0.0",
"client": {
    "organization": "Org1",
    "connection": {
        "timeout": {
            "peer": {
                "endorser": "300"
            },
            "orderer": "300"
        }
    }
},
"channels": {
    "channelall": {
        "orderers": [
            "orderer.example.com"
        ],
        "peers": {
            "peer0.org1.example.com": {
             "endorsingPeer": true,
             "chaincodeQuery": true,
             "ledgerQuery": true,
             "eventSource": true
            },

    }
},
"organizations": {
    "Org1": {
        "mspid": "Org1MSP",
        "peers": [
            "peer0.org1.example.com",
            "peer1.org1.example.com"
        ],
        "certificateAuthorities": [
            "ca.example.com"
        ],
        "adminPrivateKey": {
            "path": "/fabric-example/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/keystore/{adminkey}"
        },
        "signedCert": {
            "path": "/fabric-example/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/signcerts/Admin@org1.example.com-cert.pem"
        }
    },
    "Org2": {
        "mspid": "Org2MSP",
        "peers": [
            "peer0.org2.example.com",
            "peer1.org2.example.com"
        ],
        "certificateAuthorities": [
            "ca1.example.com"
        ],
        "adminPrivateKey": {
            "path": "/fabric-example/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/users/Admin@org2.example.com/msp/keystore/{adminkey}"
        },
        "signedCert": {
            "path": "/fabric-example/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/users/Admin@org2.example.com/msp/signcerts/Admin@org2.example.com-cert.pem"
        }
    },


},
"orderers": {
    "orderer.example.com": {
        "url": "grpc://127.0.0.1:7050",

        "grpcOptions": {
            "ssl-target-name-override": "orderer.example.com"
        },
        "tlsCACerts": {
            "path":"fabric-example/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/tlsca/tlsca.org1.example.com-cert.pem"
        }
    }
},
"peers": {
    "peer0.org1.example.com": {
        "url": "grpcs://127.0.0.1:7051",
        "grpcOptions": {
            "ssl-target-name-override": "peer0.org1.example.com"
        },
        "tlsCACerts": {
            "path": "/fabric-example/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/tlsca/tlsca.org1.example.com-cert.pem"
        }
    },
    "peer0.org2.example.com": {
        "url": "grpcs://127.0.0.1:8051",
        "grpcOptions": {
            "ssl-target-name-override": "peer0.org2.example.com"
        },
        "tlsCACerts": {
            "path": "/fabric-example/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/tlsca/tlsca.org2.example.com-cert.pem"
        }
    }
},
  "certificateAuthorities": {
    "ca.example.com": {
         "url": "https://127.0.0.1:7054",
         "tlsCACerts": {
             "path": "/fabric-example/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/tlsca/tlsca.org1.example.com-cert.pem"
         },
         "caName": "ca.example.com"
    },

    "ca2.example.com": {
        "url": "https://127.0.0.1:8054",
        "caName": "ca1.example.com",
        "tlsCACerts": {
            "path": "/fabric-example/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/tlsca/tlsca.org2.example.com-cert.pem"
        }
    }
}

 }
```

REGISTER USER

```
 'use strict';

 const { FileSystemWallet, Gateway, X509WalletMixin } = require('fabric-network');
 const fs = require('fs');
 const path = require('path');
 const ccpPath = path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'connection.json');
 const ccpJSON = fs.readFileSync(ccpPath, 'utf8');
 const ccp = JSON.parse(ccpJSON);

async function RegisterUser(user,password,roletype,affiliation) {
try {

    // Create a new file system based wallet for managing identities.
    const walletPath = path.join(process.cwd(),'wallet');
    const wallet = new FileSystemWallet(walletPath);
    console.log(`Wallet path: ${walletPath}`);

    // Check to see if we've already enrolled the user.
    const userExists = await wallet.exists(user);
    if (userExists) {
        console.log('An identity for the user  already exists in the wallet');
        return;
    }

   // Check to see if we've already enrolled the admin user.
    const adminExists = await wallet.exists('admin');
    if (!adminExists) {
        console.log('An identity for the admin user "admin" does not exist in the wallet');
        console.log('Run the enrollAdmin.js application before retrying');
        return;
    }

    // Create a new gateway for connecting to our peer node.
    const gateway = new Gateway();
    await gateway.connect(ccpPath, { wallet, identity: 'admin',discovery: { enabled: false } });

    // Get the CA client object from the gateway for interacting with the CA.

    const ca = gateway.getClient().getCertificateAuthority();
    const adminIdentity = gateway.getCurrentIdentity();



    // Register the user, enroll the user, and import the new identity into the wallet.
    const secret = await ca.register({enrollmentID:user, enrollmentSecret:password,role:roletype,affiliation:affiliation}, adminIdentity);

} catch (error) {
    console.error(`Failed to register user : ${error}`);
    process.exit(1);
}
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You use your CA to provide MSP and TLS certificates to orderers, peers and users. It normally doesn't provide its own TLS certificates (as it would require to have been started initially without TLS).

I find very strange that you use the same `tlsCACerts` for your CA and nodes. Are you sure your CA uses those `tlsCACerts`? You normally use a self-signed certificate for your CA's TLS (or a certificate from a third recognised authority).

You alway can check...

```sh
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect 127.0.0.1:7054
```

...and...

```sh
openssl x509 -text -noout -in /fabric-example/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/tlsca/tlsca.org1.example.com-cert.pem
```

...and check if the certificate of the first SSL handshake is (or is signed by) the second certificate.

You can also check your CA's logs.

---

**Edit:**

Do:

```sh
echo | openssl s_client -connect 127.0.0.1:7054 | sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' > ca1.pem
openssl X509 -text -noout -in ca1.pem
```

...and copy the result.

Copy also the result from...

```sh
openssl x509 -text -noout -in /fabric-example/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/tlsca/tlsca.org1.example.com-cert.pem
```

...so we can compare the CA TLS certificate you are using and the one you are trusting.

Comment: i am using the cryptogen tool for generating the keypairs for organisation. CA does have Tls file. which file i need to provide {certificateAuthorities tlsCACerts}  i am confused here lit bit.

Comment: thank you for replay, Is it possible to generate the self signed tls certificate using cryptogen tool.

Comment: You have some kind of fixation with `cryptogen`. Use `openssl`.